# angular 10 material datepicker cambiar el día con el que comienza la semana

Tags: angular, angular-material

He intentado buscar información sobre esto pero no consigo aclararme.

Quiero que en el calendario la semana comience con el día lunes.

Adjunto package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Código por defecto de angular material.
Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el constructor del componente se debe agregar una instancia de `DateAdapter` luego reemplazar la función `getFirstDayOfWeek()` por una que retorne `1` (lunes):

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DateAdapter } from "@angular/material/core";

/** @title Datepicker open method */
@Component({
  selector: "datepicker-api-example",
  templateUrl: "datepicker-api-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["datepicker-api-example.css"]
})
export class DatepickerApiExample {

  constructor(date: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    // retorna 1 como primer día de la semana
    date.getFirstDayOfWeek = () => 1;
  }

}
```

[Ejemplo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsuxhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-api-example.ts)

Comment: Si lo que quiero es que aparezca primero le lunes y el último el domingo, como si fuera calendario en español.

Comment: Lo que quieres entonces es cambiar el orden de las columnas de los días?

Comment: Si. como he añadido arriba que aparezca el lunes primero.

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias.